# Jquery Each Function Is Not Working How I Expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, each, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to change table values on change event. When `.woocommerce-variation` fire, new ratio is calculated by multipyling `totalvaluefirst`. Then use `totalvaluelast` to set the text. But when second event is fired, `totalvaluefirst` stays the same and the text is not changed.

```
jQuery('.woocommerce-variation').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){        
    jQuery( ".total-value" ).each(function() {
        var totalvaluefirst = (jQuery( this ).text() );

        var totalvaluefirstnew = ratio * totalvaluefirst;
        var totalvaluelast = Math.round( totalvaluelast * Math.pow(10, 2) ) / Math.pow(10, 2);  
        jQuery( this ).text(totalvaluelast);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.bind` is deprecated, use `.on` instead,

Comment: Where is `ratio` defined? Also your JS is incomplete as you're missing the last close brackets `});`

Comment: I minify code, it's working but my problem (jQuery( this ).text() ) is giving same every time.

Comment: Can you let us know what is `jQuery( ".total-value" ).length`?

Comment: What do you want to do? I guess there are multiple .woocommerce-variation elements. What you do is to calculate a different value for each element and set this as the new value for each element. This works, but you seem to want to do stuff like totaling up a bill, is that what you want?

Comment: jQuery( ".total-value" ).length is 14

Comment: Replace each with for?

Comment: @Adder I have a Installment table and there're product varitons with different prices. I want to make dynamic table when changed product variton

Comment: @NedimHozić table length is variable so I dont want to make with for. I can't understand why each function is not taking value and giving first value.

Comment: Does `ratio` get changed at all? It's probably never changed that's why your getting the same.

Comment: After jQuery( this ).text(totalvaluelast); please check is value set or not by printing  console.log(jQuery( this ).text());

Comment: You are never using the value of totalvaluefirstnew so totalvaluefirst also is never used in the final setting of the text. Also this will explode when called multiple times, unless you work with two values inside .total-value, the unchanged and the changed value.

Comment: @vijay I did and I'm seeing first value. Not changed value.

Comment: First of all this `var totalvaluelast = Math.round( totalvaluelast * Math.pow(10, 2) ) / Math.pow(10, 2);` should be `var totalvaluelast = Math.round( totalvaluefirstnew * Math.pow(10, 2) ) / Math.pow(10, 2);`.

Comment: @emrece: just check as simple string is changing or not. Like  jQuery( this ).text("simple text");

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks but my problem is (jQuery( this ).text() ); giving false value.

Comment: @vijay  jQuery( this ).text("simple text");  is working but  jQuery( this ).text(totalvaluefirst);  is writing first value which is equal to on page load.

Comment: @emrece: K may you convert your output into string and add that: E.g: var n = totalvaluelast.toString(); jQuery( this ).text(n);

Comment: @vijay same because totalvaluelast is not changing :/

Answer (score 0):

See also https://jsfiddle.net/ngfkqbvt/

I added a safeguard: when you are modifying the dom by changing the total-value it should not lead to repeated processing of the DOM event.

html:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation">
   <div class="row">1
     <div class="single-value">
     11
     </div>
     <div class="total-value">

     </div>
   <div class="row">2
     <div class="single-value">
     20
     </div>
     <div class="total-value">

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var ratio = 3.0;
var modifyingDOM = false;
jQuery('.woocommerce-variation').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){ 
    if(modifyingDOM) 
    return;
    modifyingDOM = true;
    jQuery(this).find( ".row" ).each(function() {
        var totalvaluefirst = parseInt(jQuery( this ).find(".single-value").text() );

        var totalvaluefirstnew = ratio * totalvaluefirst;
        var totalvaluelast = Math.round( totalvaluefirstnew * Math.pow(10, 2) ) / Math.pow(10, 2); 
        jQuery( this ).find(".total-value").text(totalvaluelast);
    });
    modifyingDOM = false;
});

//change the DOM
jQuery('.woocommerce-variation').trigger("DOMSubtreeModified");
```

Comment: How to change the dom? Update your fiddle!

Comment: What do you mean? I am triggering the change DOM event at the bottom.

Comment: No, I mean something like a select element so OP can check it.